# Ansible SSH Connection when using Google-Authenticator

Tags: ansible, google-authentication, pam, sshd, google-authenticator

I would like to ask a question that might not really have an answer but it will save my life.

So yesterday I started using google-authenticator for a second factor authentication on all my servers.

I am configuring all my hosts with Ansible so it is very important for me to have connection from it obviously, so, what I did, was I added this line to my `/etc/pam.d/ssh` file

```
auth [success=done default=ignore] pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/access-local.conf
```

which I think returns success if I meet the rules I added in /etc/security/access-local.conf

```
#localhost doesn't need two step verification
+ : ALL : <<localnetworkip>>/24
+ : ALL : LOCAL
#All other hosts need two step verification
- : ALL : ALL
```

So I am allowing any machine from my local network. This work when I try to ssh from my ansible to the host (it doesn't ask me for verification code) but when I try to run an ansible playbook on the same local IP I get:

> fatal: [Host]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (keyboard-interactive).", "unreachable": true}

I think Ansible doesn't know how to handle keyboard-interaction, has anyone managed to bypass it?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

So I figured out how to bypass this for my case at least.

I added the following rule at the end in  /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Match Address <<localnetworkip>>/24
    AuthenticationMethods publickey keyboard-interactive
```

So Google authentication is not mandatory anymore from internal network